# Yii Framework Dynamic Form with related fields

Tags: php, yii-extensions, yii

I working on a project that requires the following screen in the user edit account page. I am developing the project with yii framewok. I want to use multiselect inputs with data from my multi relation model and i want the form add a row of those select fields on add button.

[image: User account settings]
Any ideas how can this be done with yii. Any yii extension to customize and please suggest me a database schema?

How can this be done?? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly then you can use a single widget without using multiple inputs. Here is a good widget by cleverTech yiibooster. I think this can cater your needs by selecting multiple items.

[Select2](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/widgets/forms_inputs/view/select2.html)